# Help with deriving the Euler-Lagrange equation (evaluating at $ \varepsilon = 0$ before solving partials)

Tags: classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, variational-calculus

I am using wiki [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Lagrange_equation) to help me understand the deriving of the euler-lagrage equations

How do we get from:

\begin{equation}
\left.\frac{dJ_\varepsilon}{d\varepsilon}\right|_{\varepsilon = 0} = \int_a^b\left.\left[\eta(x)\frac{\partial L_\varepsilon}{\partial g_\varepsilon} +\eta'(x) \frac{\partial L_\varepsilon}{\partial g'_\varepsilon}\right]\right|_{\varepsilon=0} dx =0
\end{equation}

to here:

\begin{equation}
\left.\frac{dJ_\varepsilon}{d\varepsilon}\right|_{\varepsilon = 0} = \int_a^b\left[\eta(x)\frac{\partial L}{\partial f} +\eta'(x) \frac{\partial L}{\partial f'}\right] dx = 0
\end{equation}

without harming the equation. I don't know how exactly (as we must first completely work out the partials, not leaving in partial form, before evaluating at $\varepsilon = 0$).

*My guess is that partial differentiation only looks at explicit variables, and $\varepsilon$ is not explicitly in $L$, thus can we first let $\varepsilon = 0$ then work out the partial?(not sure on this)*

Is that what is happening here?

Comment: Crossposted from https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4578133/11127

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, $L_\epsilon$ is considered to only implicitly depend on $\epsilon$. Because of that, in going from $L \rightarrow L_\epsilon$, all we have done is "rename" $f\rightarrow g_\epsilon$ and $\dot{f}\rightarrow \dot{g_\epsilon}$ in $L$. This means that $L_\epsilon$ has the same functional dependence on $g_\epsilon$, as $L$ has on $f$, even though in general we cant say that $L_\epsilon = L$ (i.e. that they have the same value for the same value of $x$). Since $L_\epsilon = L(g_\epsilon, \dot{g_\epsilon},x$), $\frac{\partial L_\epsilon }{\partial g_\epsilon }= M(g_\epsilon, \dot{g_\epsilon},x)$, for some function $M$. By the "renaming" argument, it follows that $M(f,\dot f ,x)=\frac{\partial L }{\partial f }$. But $M(g_\epsilon, \dot{g_\epsilon},x)|_{\epsilon = 0}= M(f,\dot f ,x)$, so $\frac{\partial L_\epsilon }{\partial g_\epsilon} |_{\epsilon = 0}= \frac{\partial L }{\partial f }$

Answer (score 1):

In this answer I first comment on whether it is useful to try and use Wikipedia for math. Next I offer recommendations for looking elsewhere.

About using Wikipedia to try and learn a specific piece of mathematics:

Grant Sanderson (3Blue1Brown) has commented on that in a Q&A video: [math on Wikipedia](https://youtu.be/Agbh95KyWxY?t=928)

Grant Sanderson concurs that on wikipedia the available math exposition is very, very hard to understand.

To explain how that comes about Grant Sanderson offers a contrast: content that is authored by a single author, and the wikipedia way, with a multitude of authors. When something is authored by a single author there is opportunity for buildup. The author can start with the simplest case that features the thing that he wants to present. From there the author can progress to more general cases.

What tends to happen on wikipedia, says Grant Sanderson, is that there are always one or more editors who feel that presenting a simpler case first is cutting corners, and that the exposition should *start* with the *most general case*.

The result is that the exposition in a wikipedia math article is comprehensible only for a person who is already thoroughly familiar with the subject.

When it comes to derivation of the Euler-Lagrange equation my recommendation is to consult multiple authors, and take elements from each derivation.

As a starting point I point out the following two:

The [discussion of Hamilton's stationary action](https://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/II_19.html) in the Feynman lectures. (The equations aren't numbered; the relevant section starts after Figure 19-9)

The discussion by Preetum Nakkiran. Preetum Nakkiran uses the Catenary problem as motivating example for [derivation of the Euler-Lagrange equation](https://preetum.nakkiran.org/lagrange.html)