# Help with deriving euler-lagrange equation (evaluating at $ \varepsilon = 0$ before solving partials)

Tags: classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, variational-calculus

I am using wiki [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Lagrange_equation) to help me understand the deriving of the euler-lagrage equations

How do we get from:

\begin{equation}
\left.\frac{dJ_\varepsilon}{d\varepsilon}\right|_{\varepsilon = 0} = \int_a^b\left.\left[\eta(x)\frac{\partial L_\varepsilon}{\partial g_\varepsilon} +\eta'(x) \frac{\partial L_\varepsilon}{\partial g'_\varepsilon}\right]\right|_{\varepsilon=0} dx =0
\end{equation}

to here:

\begin{equation}
\left.\frac{dJ_\varepsilon}{d\varepsilon}\right|_{\varepsilon = 0} = \int_a^b\left[\eta(x)\frac{\partial L}{\partial f} +\eta'(x) \frac{\partial L}{\partial f'}\right] dx = 0
\end{equation}

without harming the equation. I don't know how exactly (as we must first completely work out the partials, not leaving in partial form, before evaluating at $\varepsilon = 0$).

*My guess is that partial differentiation only looks at explicit variables, and $\varepsilon$ is not explicitly in $L$, thus can we first let $\varepsilon = 0$ then work out the partial?(not sure on this)*

Is that what is happening here?

Comment: Possible duplicate by OP: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/737199/2451

Comment: Hi Reuben. Welcome to Phys.SE. Please don't repost a closed question in a new entry. Instead, you are supposed to edit the original question within the original entry.

Comment: @Qmechanic , I thought it would disappear once deleted.

Comment: @Qmechanic, but now I got 2 closed questions and no one is going to answer this question which I have been trying so hard to get the answer to :_(

Comment: Try paste the 2nd post into the 1st post.

Comment: @Qmechanic, done